# Easiest way to bridge 1Gbps Ethernet with 1Gbps WiFi?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

I have an cable modem/WiFi router (802.11ac) and am paying for a 1000mbps internet plan. My 16” MacBook Pro only gets about 220mbps over its 802.11ac adaptor @ 5GHz. The MacBook is located in a room directly underneath the modem/router with only a typical 2x4 wood framed floor between them. The problem is that there is no way to run a cat5 cable from the modem/router to that room below it where the MacBook is. So I am looking for the cheapest way to get a reliably 1000mbps+ WiFi connection between my MacBook and the modem/router’s Ethernet port. I do already have a usb-c 1000mbps Ethernet adaptor.

Maybe there is a simple two-piece WiFi 6 system that can stand in for an Ethernet cable without paying $350+ for a mesh system? Or some other way?

Comment: What is the problem connecting directly to the (WLAN)-router? Does the signal get better if you are next to the router? Did you try to move the router closer to the laptop (minimize the distance with just the floor in between)? Did you check how the router's radiation profil? Maybe it will be enough to adjust it's orientation? Did you check the setting? Boost the signal etc?

Or in general - what have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? A little more info would be helpfull... ; ) [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It doesn't help if the MacBook is right next to the router, which is a brand-new DOCSIS 802.11ac model/router. So I assume that is the limit of the wireless tech. It is impossible to run a cat5 from where I am to the router.

Comment: I thought you can get a bit more out of the current devices. But if distance/obstruction do not slow your network speed it's pretty save to assume that this is your current limit unless the configuration is messed up. Note that not all devices support the "full capabilities" of 802.11ac, that applies to your AP/router as well as the WLAN card of your end device. In general I would assume you can get more speed over WLAN and that the WLAN-NIC in your MacBook is the limiting factor. But for questions on that I would open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "simplest" way will most likely be a "Powerline Ethernet" connection **if** your power line quality/distribution meets it's requirements. You should make sure to use a [G.hn-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.hn) product. Theoretically it can handle data up to 2Gbps but you might wanna check e.g. [this source](https://specklepattern.wordpress.com/2020/01/11/powerline-reality-actual-bandwidth-versus-headline-bandwidth/) before buying. Also consider your "real Internet speed" which most likely won't be 1Gbps.

Other then that, you will probable be able to get more out of your current WLAN with the right HW and/or configuration (see my comment to your question).

Comment: Only the most recent version (G.hn) can come close to what the OP demands in terms of throughput.

Comment: @DanielB good point, thanks. [Here's ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G.hn) some more information including vendors for G.hn-compliant products.

Comment: I tried a Netgear Powerline 1Gbps product that got 250mbps from wall power sockets 2 feet apart, so I can only assume that a G.hn-compliant product wouldn't solve it. But I do think this is a good answer to the original question, which should not have had "wifi" in the title.

Comment: Thanks. Buying WiFi6 HW my not be such a bad move... you might wanna check prices.Since the floor panels don't seem to obstruct the signal too much it might be possible to get a higher data rate with WiFI5 HW as well. Theoretically 802.11ac can support up to 3.39 Gbit/s with 4 streams on 160 MHz. Assuming you find HW which implements the full specs.

Answer (score 1):

The advertising for 802.11ac access points is a bit misleading: usually the total bandwidth of the access point is given, not the per-stream capacity, which depends on the number of antennas in both the access point and the mobile device, on whether there are actually distinguishable different paths, and on the frequency used.

Since you're using only a single device, you are seeing the stream capacity of that connection. 200 Mbps is roughly what I get as well, but regardless of what my flatmate is doing.

If you want 1 Gbps for a single station, you will have to go wired. There may be adapters that can actually achieve that wirelessly, but only under optimum conditions, with the access point in the same room and the station near the plane that the antennas are arranged on (which is likely horizontal, so if you're on a different floor, that would be a problem).

Powerline adapters as suggested by Albin are very hit-and-miss. If you can, do proper Cat6 wiring.

Comment: Although I agree in general, a small (theoretical) addition: with the right HW and configuration 802.11ac can support more then 1 Gbps you don't necessarily have to go wired (up to 3.39 Gbit/s with 4 streams on 160 MHz). And Cat5e can support 1 Gbps speeds as well.